# latest 50 documents from mongodb

Tags: performance, mongodb

In order to show latest 10 news to user My application is fetching all news from collection news and then I am sorting them on date field of document and displaying them top 10.

This was fine when I had 100-1000 news now news in the collection has grown and it growing. I want to fetch t(can be 20, 50, or 100) latest news (that can be figured out from date field or based on latest t inserted documents if something like this is supported)

Is there any way to achieve this in MongoDB. Its basically for improving the performance of find?

Note I am not talking about fetching any 10 document.I am specific on the last 10(t) entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly why [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) and [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) are.

`db.news.find().sort({timeField : 1}).limit(10);` if you have some timestamp field
`db.news.find().sort({$natural : -1}).limit(10);` if you want based on latest inserted

Comment: `db.news.find().sort({$natural : 1}).limit(10);` should be `db.news.find().sort({$natural : -1}).limit(10);`

Comment: I doubt the first one should also be `{timeField:-1}`? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer even I found something like this but I doubted that my filters like sort and limit are working on the find result. Is this all working as one command or this is applied on the result of find.

Answer (score 0):

Well after alot of browsing I found Sort and Limit is what I needed. Few things that are to be kept in mind. Sort Works well with indexes in mongodb so better create one if you are sure about the field you need for sorting this boost the performance. Also ensure the size limitation on sort that depends on available RAM. Order of sort and limit does not matter. As answered above $natural is the field that helps to sort on order in which data is inserted in mongodb.